# What parts of the Novena are not open source?

Tags: hardware

[Novena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novena_(computing_platform)) tries to be an open source computing platform. But so far it's only [partially open source](http://www.wired.com/2014/04/novena/). Which parts are still not open source and have to be replaced to create a fully open source platform?

The Novena has [abundance of documentation](http://www.kosagi.com/w/index.php?title=Novena_Main_Page), but its mass is overwhelming and it is hard to understand without electronic engineering knowledge, for instance [this schematic](http://bunniefoo.com/novena/pvt1_release/novena_pvt1.PDF). So I find myself unable to extract the information to answer my question, although it is probably hidden in this documentation.

Comment: How can anyone outside their team answer this?

Comment: @bmargulies: As their documentation is open, someone should be able to see what is covered and what not.

Comment: Why do you want someone else to read their documentation for you and type an answer here?

Comment: @Mnementh so you're inviting downvotes for lack of research ;-)

Comment: @StephenKitt: So? Can you provide after two minutes googling a link that answers my question? The documentation contains wiring diagrams. I have difficulties reading this, as I'm not an electrical engineer.

Comment: @Mnementh That's understandable, you should mention that in your question. (FTR I didn't down-vote...)

Answer (score 4):

The official website containing the documentation can be found [here](https://novena-guide.readthedocs.org/en/PVT2/source-licensing.html). It seems that they have not made official documentation yet.

**However,**

The [article](http://www.wired.com/2014/04/novena/) you linked to, is over a year and a half old. Since then numerous other articles have been released saying it is now **fully** open source:

- [First Totally Open Source Software](http://www.wired.com/2014/01/open-source-laptop/)
- [Open source laptop](http://techcrunch.com/2014/05/18/novena-the-crowdsourced-fully-open-laptop-is-shipping-this-winter/)
- [Fully open sourced laptop](http://techpp.com/2014/04/03/novena-fully-open-source-laptop/)

So to answer your question:

The entire laptop is open source - with one exception to this being the processor (a Cortex A9 CPU).

Comment: A Cortex A9 CPU is now open source? Somehow I doubt that.

Comment: Ok, sorry did not see that.. Have double checked now.. and fixed the mistake

Comment: Do you think the processor is the only exception? That was my question about, which parts are not. I'm unsure if these articles checked thoroughly.

Comment: One of your articles write: "For now, the Novena is probably as close as it gets to a truly open source laptop" - as close as it gets != completely

Comment: Yes I do think the processor is the only part.

Comment: I do think? Any real sources?

Comment: I provided numerous sources. However, I am not going to provide links to show that EVERY OTHER item on the parts list is open source. I have looked through them and googled all the parts that gave me the slightest bit of doubt. I am sure it is the ONLY non open source part